# Transfer the code of a custom plugin into a theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, wordpress-theming

I am working on a new project on WordPress.
I am developing a new website for a client based on their actual site (developed by an other team).
So, I decided to create a new WordPress theme and to use the existing content (client's request).
However, this supposes to reuse the custom plugins, in order to not re upload the pictures and the articles by hand.
I would like to include the custom plugins into the new theme. However, the plugins folder is outside the theme folder. So I was wondering if you have an idea on how I could transfer the code of a custom plugin into the new theme.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What custom plugins are being used to handle pictures and articles? Uploaded files should go to /wp-content/uploads and all data is stored in the database. Removing the plugins might make the data inaccessible, but it shouldn't disappear.

Why are you moving functions from plugins to a theme? Or are these plugins inside of the /wp-content/themes/ folder? The way you handle the two cases is very different.

If you *need* to copy certain functions into a theme, you can move them into a functions.php file (or a functions.php file that calls to other files in that directory) in a child theme. The WordPress Codex has much better [documentation on child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) than I could ever outline here. Placing the functions into your main theme is a permanent change and is not recommended when you're dealing with functions that are better-suited to plugins.

If you're copying plugins from one theme into another, you might want to look at plugin dependencies using [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/).